# How to allowNamespaces in CRA?

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, react-scripts

I created a TypeScript React app using:

```sh
yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript
```

This way, my project is compiled with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and then bundled by [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). Now I want to use TypeScript [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html), which aren't supported in Babel by default, but they [can be enabled](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript#allownamespaces). I installed all the necessary packages:

- [`@babel/plugin-transform-typescript`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript)
- [`react-app-rewired`](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/)
- [`customize-cra`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/)

In `package.json` I changed `react-scripts start` to `react-app-rewired start`.

Finally, I created a `config-overrides.js` file:

```js
const {
    override,
    addExternalBabelPlugin
  } = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = override(
    addExternalBabelPlugin([
        "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript",
        { allowNamespaces: true }
    ])
);
```

However, compilation still throws a syntax error, as if no plugin was enabled:

> SyntaxError: /home/m93a/my-app/script.ts: Namespace not marked type-only declare. Non-declarative namespaces are only supported experimentally in Babel. To enable and review caveats see: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript

How do I set up my project correctly, so that it compiles even non-declarative namespaces?

---

**EDIT**: The reason why my project didn't work was actually quite different from what I thought. Check my own answer for more details.

Comment: I would recommend just using `ts-loader` instead of `babel` and turn on `jsx` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @LuketheGeek CRA uses Babel and the [`@babel/preset-typescript`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript) plugin. `ts-loader` has nothing to do with this problem nor CRA.

Comment: @m93a I've added a working demo repository to my answer. Please check it out to see if a single namespaced class I've got (*`People.Person` inside `src/lib/Person.ts`*) is in the same shape as yours. Did you try `addBabelPlugin`? If it did not work for you, please provide an example of how you declare and using the namespaces. There is also the `.babelrc` option that I can add it to my answer if you want to try it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [`addBabelPlugin`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md#addbabelpluginplugin) instead of [`addExternalBabelPlugin`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md#addexternalbabelpluginplugin).

### tl;dr

If we check the documentation, we see:

> ### [`addExternalBabelPlugin(plugin)`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md#addexternalbabelpluginplugin)
>
> `create-react-app` actually has two rules in its `webpack` config for `babel-loader`: one for code in `addSrc` (`src/` by default) and the other for code `external` to that folder (like `node_modules`). You can add plugins to the `external` loader using `addExternalBabelPlugin` in the same way you'd use `addBabelPlugin`.

and if we check inside [`react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js) we can see these two `babel-loader` entries:

1. At [`webpack.config.js#L396`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L396) there is the `babel-loader` for the `include: paths.appSrc` and for `\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/` which [`addBabelPlugin`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md#addbabelpluginplugin) add plugins for, with the comment:

   > ```
   > // Process application JS with Babel.
   > // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
   > ```
2. At [`webpack.config.js#L452`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L452) is the `babel-loader` for `/\.(js|mjs)$/` which [`addExternalBabelPlugin`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md#addexternalbabelpluginplugin) add plugins for, with the comment:

   > ```
   > // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
   > // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
   > ```

We want [`@babel/plugin-transform-typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-transform-typescript) to apply to the first `babel-loader` regarding application `src` folder so we have to use [`addBabelPlugin`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md#addbabelpluginplugin) that applies to that `babel-loader` configuration.

Last but not least, make sure you have updated your `package.json` scripts to run from `react-app-rewired`:

```json
"start": "react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired build",
"test": "react-app-rewired test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

You can check a very simple CRA Typescript project using a class from a namespace here: https://github.com/clytras/cra-ts-namespaces

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely the best answer to the exact question I posed. However, Masih's earlier answer would work for me too, if it wasn't for reasons mentioned in my own answer. Masih's several different attempts to solve the issue helped me discover the bug. So, I hope you'll understand when I award the bounty to him. Thank you once again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

**Use rescripts to overwrite Babel config**
So follow these steps:

1. Create new app with `create-react-app my-app --template=typescript` or use an existing one
2. Install [rescripts](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts) with `npm i -D @rescripts/cli`
3. Replace react-scripts with rescripts in `package.json` like in [rescripts docs](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts#1-replace-react-scripts-calls-with-rescripts-calls)
4. Install rescript plugin for babel config `@rescripts/rescript-use-babel-config`
5. Add this snipper to your `package.json` file

```
"rescripts": [
    [
        "use-babel-config",
            {
                "presets": [
                    "react-app",
                    [
                        "@babel/preset-typescript",
                        {
                            "allowNamespaces": true
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
```

Rescripts will use plugin, which will extend babel config. We extend default react-app babel config, so we don't break anything. Then we overwrite preset (already installed by react-app), but we set `allowNamespaces` flag.

Comment: Please avoid providing multiple answers to one question. You can include all methods and instructions regarding solutions in one answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. Do you test this answer?

Comment: Thank you for your time, Masih! You helped me to find the solution, although problem wasn't exactly where I thought it was. Although the other answer provides the simplest solution to the exact question, your work was what helped to solve the real world problem I had.

Comment: @MasihJahangiri - Is there a way to have this also affect testing with Jest?

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case, the reason why I couldn't get it working, even when I followed others' advice, was the following: There is a bug in Babel that prevents it from merging `enum` and `namespace`. This code, for example, wouldn't work:

```js
export enum Foo
{
    a, b, c, d
}

export namespace Foo
{
  export function bar()
  {
    return "bar"
  }
}
```

But for some weird reason, Babel throws a very misleading error when it encounters this code:

> SyntaxError: script.ts: Namespace not marked type-only declare. Non-declarative namespaces are only supported experimentally in Babel. To enable and review caveats see: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript

I filed [an issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11460), so hopefully this bug gets fixed soon, or at least gets a decent error message. In the meantime, a walkaround can be used:

```js
export enum Foo_
{
    a, b, c, d
}

export type Foo = Foo_

export namespace Foo
{
  export const a = Foo_.a
  export const b = Foo_.b
  export const c = Foo_.c
  export const d = Foo_.d
  export function bar()
  {
    return "bar"
  }
}
```